# installing exfat-fuse: Error: can't find signing_key_fingerprint

Tags: 10.04, filesystem, exfat

I have a samsung evo 64gb, which has apparently been formatted with the microsoft exfat filesystem. I wish to mount it on an ubuntu 10.04 system.

There are many responses in respect of how to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils fuse-exfat
```

However, I am getting stuck at the first step:

```
# apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
Error: can't find signing_key_fingerprint at https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~relan/+archive/exfat
```

How can I resolve this error?